# How to register when Revit start but fail to get a licene c#

Tags: c#, api, revit

Using Revit API, I am trying to register all the user in my company when they start Revit.I used the onstart and on shutdown function in an application to monitor that.

The problem are those who fail to get license from the license server, because all the licenses are taken, the onstart function doesn't feel them. How to capture those who try to get a license.
RGRDS

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Windows API to catch and log the launch of Revit.exe. Then, secondly, you could catch and launch the OnStartup event handler call. If you detect the former without the latter, you have what you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy. I actually catch only OnStartup, how to use the Windows API I have no idea on but I'll try to search. Thanks again!

Comment: windows detect process start: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+detect+process+start